# Javascript Variable undefined Without Alert

Tags: javascript

So I have a section of code for a program I working on that reads in other text files that are specified inside of the first file. However, I am having some problems with my variable, newText and txt. If I use the javascript alert, it will work, but if I take out the alert(txt); my code breaks, and newText is undefined.

```
function createStates(textArr, numStates, acts)
{
    textArr.splice();
    var states = [];
    var path = window.prompt("Please enter the path to your state files", "");
    for( var i =0; i < numStates; i++)
    {
        // reward for being in state, terminal, then statefile

        var reward = parseInt(textArr.shift());
        var terminal = parseInt(textArr.shift());
        if(terminal == 0)
        {
            var newText = [];
            var nextFile = path + String(textArr[0]);
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var txt;
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
                    txt = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    newText = String(txt).split(/[\r\n]+/g);
                }
            };;
            xmlhttp.open("GET","file:///" + nextFile,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            alert(txt);
            var state = new State(reward, acts, newText);
            states.push(state);

        }
        textArr.shift();
    }
    return states;
}
```

Alse, here is what one of the text files that it is handling looks like,

```
4 11
0 0 0 0 0 0 0.8 0 0 0.1 0.1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0.1 0 0 0.8 0.1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.1 0.9
0 0 0 0 0 0 0.1 0 0 0 0.9
```

And this is for a school project, and I have to read in the files from a local computer. I am using firefox to run this since chrome blocks the loading of local files.

Comment: `newText` is set when the AJAX request is completed. Without the alert, you aren't waiting enough time for it to be completed. Look up how asynchronous functions work in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will return `true` if variable is not defined in global scope

```
window.txt === undefined
```